# Python: Could not install tensorflow due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.10

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\GCIT\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_github_grpc_grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths

I was trying to install tensorflow on my windows but the error popout